# find_by_sql equivalent for mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there some sort of find_by_sql equivalent for mongoid, where you pass a mongo query and it materializes Mongoid::Document s from the results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongoid wraps the Collection object to return objects of the proper class.

So, if User is a Mongoid model:

```
cursor = User.collection.find({}, {}) # Just like the Ruby driver...
records = cursor.to_a # An array of User objects
```

Edit to add: It actually wraps Mongo's Cursor class too. [See here:](http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/cursor.rb#L42-46)

```
def each
  @cursor.each do |document|
    yield Mongoid::Factory.build(@klass, document)
  end
end
```

Comment: that is absolutely amazing! do you know how the mongo driver knows to materialize my mongoid class?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mongoid 3, it provides easy access to its MongoDB driver: [Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/). Here's an example of accessing some raw data without using Models to access the data:

```
db = Mongoid::Sessions.default
collection = db[:collection_name]

# finding a document
doc = collection.find(name: 'my new document').first

collection.find.each do |document|
  puts document.inspect
end
```