# How to fire raw MongoDB queries directly in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Is there any way that I can fire a raw mongo query directly in Ruby instead of converting them to the native Ruby objects?

I went through Ruby Mongo Tutorial, but I cannot find such a method anywhere.

If it were mysql, I would have fired a query something like this.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select * from foo")
```

My mongo query is a bit large and it is properly executing in the MongoDB console. What I want is to directly execute the same inside Ruby code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a (possibly) better mini-tutorial on how to get directly into the guts of your MongoDB. This might not solve your specific problem but it should get you as far as the MongoDB version of `SELECT * FROM table`.

---

First of all, you'll want a [`Mongo::Connection`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html) object. If
you're using [MongoMapper](http://mongomapper.com/) then you can call the `connection`
class method on any of your MongoMapper models to get a connection
or ask MongoMapper for it directly:

```
connection = YourMongoModel.connection
connection = MongoMapper.connection
```

Otherwise I guess you'd use the [`from_uri`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html#from_uri-class_method) constructor to build
your own connection.

Then you need to get your hands on a database, you can do this
using the [array access notation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html#%5B%5D-instance_method), the [`db`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html#db-instance_method) method, or get
the current one straight from MongoMapper:

```
db = connection['database_name']    # This does not support options.
db = connection.db('database_name') # This does support options.
db = MongoMapper.database           # This should be configured like
                                    # the rest of your app.
```

Now you have a nice shiny [`Mongo::DB`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html) instance in your hands. 
But, you probably want a [`Collection`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html) to do anything interesting
and you can get that using either array access notation or the
[`collection`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html#collection-instance_method) method:

```
collection = db['collection_name']
collection = db.collection('collection_name')
```

Now you have something that behaves sort of like an SQL table so 
you can [`count`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#count-instance_method) how many things it has or query it using [`find`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method):

```
cursor = collection.find(:key => 'value')
cursor = collection.find({:key => 'value'}, :fields => ['just', 'these', 'fields'])
# etc.
```

And now you have what you're really after: a hot out of the oven [`Mongo::Cursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html) 
that points at the data you're interested in. `Mongo::Cursor` is 
an [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) so you have access to all your usual iterating 
friends such as [`each`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#each-instance_method), [`first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001498), [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001491), and one of my personal
favorites, [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516):

```
a = cursor.each_with_object([]) { |x, a| a.push(mangle(x)) }
```

There are also [`command`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html#command-instance_method) and [`eval`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html#eval-instance_method) methods on `Mongo::DB` that might do what you want.

Comment: what version of mongoid is this?

Comment: @newdark I don't see any references to Mongoid up there. That was based on whatever version of MongoMapper was current six years ago which AFAIK used the Ruby interface directly from the MongoDB people.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using mongoid you will find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730336/find-by-sql-equivalent-for-mongoid/3730514).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mongoid 3, it provides easy access to its MongoDB driver: [Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/). Here's an example of accessing some raw data without using Models to access the data:

```
db = Mongoid::Sessions.default

# inserting a new document
collection = db[:collection_name]
collection.insert(name: 'my new document')

# finding a document
doc = collection.find(name: 'my new document').first

# "select * from collection"
collection.find.each do |document|
  puts document.inspect
end
```