# MongoDB, Ruby do not display id field?

Tags: ruby, shell, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. Just wondering:

How do I convert this shell command to ruby?

```
db.unicorns.find(null, {name: 1, _id:0});
```

This gives me an error:

```
db.collection("unicorns").find(nil, :fields=>["name","_id"=>0])
```

If you have any tutorial resources as well, would appreciate :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That [should almost work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553330/479863). The error you're getting is something like this:

> TypeError: keys must be strings or symbols

right? Just use a Hash for fields instead of an Array:

```
db.collection("unicorns").find(nil, :fields => { :name => true, :_id => false })
```

So it is pretty much a straight transliteration of the JavaScript version.

Sorry, I don't know of any tutorials on this stuff let alone good ones. I've figured it out myself through guess work and extrapolating the JavaScript docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Was bit of a headbanger.