# Ruby GridFS - Search on filename

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs

In ruby using the mongo gem I can't find any documentation on how to find on a filename with GridFs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First [get a connection to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6548061/479863), we'll call this `db`. Then you can connect to your GridFS as a [Mongo::Grid](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Grid.html) or [Mongo::GridFileSystem](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/GridFileSystem.html) instance:

```
fs = Mongo::Grid.new(db)
fs = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(db)
```

Now you can use the [Mongo::GridExt::InstanceMethods](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/GridExt/InstanceMethods.html) methods on `fs`. In particular, you can use `exist?`:

```
f = fs.exist? :filename => 'pancakes.png'
```

The `exist?` method is poorly named as it gives you a Hash if it finds something and a `nil` if it doesn't.

That's not terribly useful if you're searching for, say, all filenames that match `/pancakes/`. However, GridFS is just a pair of normal MongoDB collections:

- `fs.files`: the file metadata.
- `fs.chunks`: the file data (in chunks).

If you want to do arbitrary metadata searches then you just need to get your hands on `fs.files` and have your way with it:

```
fs     = db['fs.files']
cursor = fs.find(:filename => /pancakes/)
# Now iterate through cursor or .count it or ...
```

The `fs` above will be a [Mongo::Collection](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html) so its [`find` method](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method) accepts all the usual query options.