# Executing raw MongoDB queries in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid3

I have the follow raw mongo query that I want to execute directly in my Rails controller:

```
 db.user_places.update({place_id: destroy_model.id}, {$set: {place_id: keep_model.id}}, false, true)
```

For sequel, I was using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` to execute my sql queries.

What's the equivalent way of doing this using MongoDB/mongoid gem? I've tried following [How to fire raw MongoDB queries directly in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548061/how-to-fire-raw-mongodb-queries-directly-in-ruby),  but I'm not using MongoMapper.

Thank you.

Edit: My solution to this problem was to just run the following from Mongoid documentation:

`UserPlace.where(place_id: destroy_model.id).update_all(place_id: keep_model.id)`

This will generate the raw mongo query above and execute it in ActiveRecord fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it without have to establish a connection with Mongo console. Using mongoid, you can just use the update_all to generate the same query.